Can't connect to Eduroam with Ubuntu 24.04
I have a fresh 24.04 install on a brand new laptop.
Can connect to any network, but Eduroam, which is the only option at my work place. Did not have any problem with my previous machine with Eduroam, but I was on 22.04 instead.
I can install the certificates from my uni and can see the wifi network, but I can't connect. A message pops up saying I need passwords (which I already configured manually in the network config).
Also tried the fixes from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1958267 but they don't seem to work. I suspect the problem is with openssl, but can't say for sure.
Would like some help
Thank you

1.Verify Configuration:
•Ensure settings like WPA2-Enterprise, PEAP (version 0), MSCHAPv2, and CA certificate (or "Do not validate") are correct.
2.Install Required Packages: You might be missing some required libraries for the encryption or network handshake process. Open a terminal and run the following to ensure all necessary packages are installed:
sudo apt update sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome
wpasupplicant ca-certificates openssl

3.Check for OpenSSL Issues:
Since you suspect the problem could be related to OpenSSL, check if the certificates are correctly processed:
•Run the following to verify OpenSSL version:
openssl version

If it's outdated or has compatibility issues, upgrading OpenSSL might help. You can upgrade by running:
sudo apt update sudo apt install --only-upgrade openssl

4.Disable IPv6: Some eduroam networks have issues with IPv6. To disable IPv6:
• Edit the GRUB file:
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

• Add the following to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX:
ipv6.disable=1

Save the file, then update grub:
sudo update-grub sudo reboot

5.Manually Add Eduroam Network: If GUI settings don’t work, you can manually add the eduroam connection via nmcli (Network Manager Command Line Interface):
sudo nmcli dev wifi connect eduroam --ask

It will ask for the necessary credentials and try connecting
6.Check Logs for More Insights: If the above steps don't resolve the issue, checking logs might help identify the root cause:
journalctl -xe | grep NetworkManager

Look for any errors or warnings that could provide more specific insight into why the connection fails.
7.Ensure CA Certificate Trust: Some networks require a CA certificate to be installed. You can try adding the certificate manually via:
sudo cp /path/to/cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ 
sudo update-ca-certificates


Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Format the pasted output from the terminal as code using the {_} icon above the edit window or the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+K in the future.
